# How to see the shift and scale of a trained RealNVP in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

For example this:

https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/bijectors/RealNVP

There is some sort of function:

nvp.bijector._shift_and_log_scale_f

But it is not obvious what to give up. Is there a convenience function?